# Civic 2007 fuel smell when idle

Tags: honda, civic, fuel-leak

I have a 2007 civic. For the last month the car has a faint gasoline smell in the cabin.

The smells only happens when :
*) The car is idling 
*) Air is on.

It does NOT happen when 
*) The car is moving
*) If I turn the air off.

A month back I changed all 4 spark plugs but I replaced with platnium spark plugs instead of irdium (OEM plug). My wife told me that she thinks this is around when she started smelling the fumes. This was also around the time we just got the car back from the mechanic. The mechanic had to replace the power steering return line.

I'm thinking of just removing all the spark plugs and cleaning the seating area and reinstalling. I don't think irdium plugs burn hotter than platinum, so I'm thinking there is blow by.

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about diagnosing this? I think it's fumes coming from the engine because if it was a fuel line leak I would smell it all the time.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Likely a fuel leak , you don't smell it when the car is moving because the much greater air flow carries away most fumes . I would check as soon as possible.

Comment: But I also don't smell it when the air is off. Usually fuel leaks you smell it all the time. I am fairly confident it coming from the front of the car but I did check and couldn't find anything of concern.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Two of the spark plugs were not torqued down correctly.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as "the answer" as soon as the system will let you :o)